# How to find accuracy of k-means clustering algorithm

Tags: unsupervised-learning

I am performing unsupervised learning on unlabeled data using k-means clustering.I dont have any training data available with me.How to measure the accuracy of the algorithm?How to validate the results that I have obtained?

Comment: *Why* are you clustering your data points? That should give you a clue how to validate.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tell you that there is no exact number of clusters, but there are some ways to validate.

First, you can use similarity calculation between elements in a cluster, including:

- Pearson Correlation
- Euclidean Distance
- or Cosine Correlation

More than that, among clusters, you can see that they are really separated or not by using:

- Single Linkage
- Complete Linkage
- or Average Linkage

Dunn Index, Rand Index or Purity are also good candidates for evaluating your clustering result.